# Equation with n-th root (and unknown variable x)

Tags: analysis, contest-math, radicals

$\sqrt[n]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[n]{(x-1)^2}=4\sqrt[n]{x^2-1}\Big/:2$

$\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x+1)^2}}{2}-\sqrt[n]{x^2-1}+\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x-1)^2}}{2}=\sqrt[n]{x^2-1}$

$\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)^{2}-2\cdot\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x-1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)+\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x-1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)^{2}=\sqrt[n]{x^2-1}$

$\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x-1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)^{2}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x-1)}}{\sqrt{2}}$

$\Bigg|\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x-1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg|=\sqrt[2n]{x^2-1}$

$\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{(x-1)}}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt[2n]{x^2-1}$

I don't know how to continue.

Task from a contest in Poland, 1960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x+1)^{1/n}=a, (x-1)^{1/n}=b$

$\implies a^2+b^2=4ab\iff\left(\dfrac ab\right)^2-4\cdot\dfrac ab+1=0$

$\dfrac ab=2\pm\sqrt3$

$$\implies\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}=\left(\dfrac ab\right)^n$$

Comment: thank you. I would never come up with that idea.